# Create Site Workflow with sp.workflowservices.js using Javascript

Tags: workflow, site, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created SharePoint Hosted app and Now I want to create site workflow using javascript.

I have create list workflow using javascript with the help of sp.workflowservices.js library.

So is it possible to create site workflow using javascript